# Uber API credentials disclosure

Tags: uber-api

I'd like to make an AngularJS app (no server side code at all) that uses Uber API [history](https://developer.uber.com/docs/rides/api/v12-history) and [requests-details](https://developer.uber.com/docs/rides/api/v1-requests-details) endpoints.

As far as I understood the docs I'll need to use OAuth2 first and to get the access token the *client_secret* is required.

As it is a client-side application, *client_secret* can be seen by any user (easily or not).

I'm trying to understand the impact of exposing the *client_secret* but I cannot find anything bad about it from the docs.
There doesn't seem to be any *client_secret* endpoint that does anything harmful without the bearer token.

Answer (score 1):

The client secret is the shared secret between the oauth server and the client application. Anyone who possesses the client secret for an application can represent as that application. So if it's leaked, a malicious application can:

- Request permissions from users under the guise of your application
- Request scopes that your application had been whitelisted for (e.g. the "request" scope)
- Request an access token for your application using the client credentials grant flow (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3.4)
- Perform other malicious activities as your application

Comment: Yes but this was more of a question towards uber api specifically, not OAuth in general. Point 1; I haven't found anything in the docs that an application can request about an user without the OAuth Bearer token itself. Point 2; the scopes I'd be using are available to any other application. Point 3; not sure I understood this one but it seems it wouldn't apply to a "desktop" application. Also, even if they direct a user to OAuth using my app id, the redirect won't go back to their page as redirect URL is also configured (I believe)